# how can i make a cube with a grid in three.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, 3d

[Cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bmGNT.png)

I want to make something exactly like this but I can change the amount of cubes in the grid with a variable.(I have no idea how to start)

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to add the cubes to a `Group`, then add that `Group` to a scene, then centre the `Group`

Here is one approach of doing this:

```js
const grid = new THREE.Group();

const cubeSize = 0.25;
const rows = 4;
const cols = 4;
const gap = 0.01;

for (let row = 0; row < rows; row++) {
    for (let col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
        for (let z = 0; z < rows; z++) {
            const cube = createCube(cubeSize);
            const pos = ((cubeSize / 2) * rows) / 2 + gap;
            const x = pos * row;
            const y = pos * col;
            cube.position.set(x, y, pos * z);
            grid.add(cube);
        }
    }
}

scene.add(grid);
```

Note, this won't scale well the more cubes you add. Since the the total number of objects will be `(rows + cols) ^ 3`, which will produce a large number of objects. In light of this, you can use `InstancedMesh` mesh, which I have shown a demo of below.

Demo:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script type="module">
  import * as THREE from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/build/three.module.js";
  import { OrbitControls } from "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";

  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
    75,
    window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight,
    0.1,
    1000
  );
  const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

  const grid = new THREE.Group();

  const cubeSize = 0.25;
  const size = 20;
  const gap = 0.01;

  const geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(
    cubeSize,
    cubeSize,
    cubeSize
  );
  const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();
  const cubes = new THREE.InstancedMesh(
    geometry,
    material,
    Math.pow(size, 3)
  );
  cubes.instanceMatrix.setUsage(THREE.DynamicDrawUsage);

  grid.add(cubes);
  scene.add(grid);

  const cube = new THREE.Object3D();
  const center = (size + gap * (size - 1)) * -0.5;

  grid.position.set(center, center, center);

  camera.position.z = size * 1.5;

  (function animate() {
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);

    let i = 0;
    for (let x = 0; x < size; x++) {
      for (let y = 0; y < size; y++) {
        for (let z = 0; z < size; z++) {
          cube.position.set(x, y, z);
          cube.updateMatrix();
          cubes.setMatrixAt(i, cube.matrix);
          i++;
        }
      }
    }

    cubes.instanceMatrix.needsUpdate = true;

    controls.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
  })();
</script>
```

Comment: that works but i cant  put 126 cubes using that code and the thing i want to do is to  input a number that is shown in 3d in cubes.

Comment: The square root of the sum of `rows` and `cols` needs to be an integer. The square root of 126 is 11.224972160321824 which is not a whole number, meaning the grid won't be a square

Comment: 126 is also way too many to render with this method. You will need to use instancing to achieve that. Any number entered into the "input" will be cubed, and 126^3 is over 2 million cubes

Comment: yeah I understand that but is there a way to do it without rows or cols and just input a number and that number be shown in cubes like there is a cube in the center and all the other cubes are based off his position ?

Comment: I'm updating my answer now to include an `InstancedMesh` example

Comment: @DlyzeI I've updated my answer

Comment: thanks for your help but I have one more question can I make the cubes in a grid without 'Math.pow(size,3)' and instead put size like this                                     const cubes = new THREE.InstancedMesh(
    geometry,
    material,
    size ); because i need the user to input a certain number and it being showed in a gird it doesnt have to be a cube

Comment: You can but it would not be a cube shape, since you need to do n^3 to make a cube